# How to checkout commit in GitKraken?

Tags: git, gitkraken

It seems to be impossible to checkout commits with GitKraken.

[image: Gitkraken commits options]

As you can see there is no option to checkout older commits, only `Cherrypick commit` but I don't know what this is good for.

EDIT: I was able to checkout with another git program (git bash) via console:

[image: console]

Now it looks like this in GitKraken:

[image: gitkraken current head on specific commit]

Comment: Can someone explain `cherry pick`?

Comment: It basically means you can pick changes from another commit in the same repository (e.g., from another branch) and commit them to the current branch as if the changes were done locally. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Answer (score 40, accepted):

GitKraken (as of version 1.7) does not seem to offer a way to get into a detached HEAD mode, and check out a commit directly. Similarly, it will also not allow you to check out a tag (since that would also give you a detached HEAD).

So instead, you will have to create a (temporary) branch first which you can then check out.

Comment: ohh what a pitty... I thought it is such a great software, but this is obviously an important feature which is missing. Then I will have to use external programs everytime if I want to checkout older commits... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Since GitKraken is actively being developed, it probably wouldn’t hurt to create a feature request for this. You can do that via the *Help* menu.

Comment: I've created a feature request months ago, but it is still not implemented. Seems to be a complicated task.

Comment: I can't seem to find the feature requests. Is that a paid feature only to have access to the bug tracker?

Comment: @Jdban101 It’s possible that they have removed it since I originally posted this. Back then, they had a way to provide feedback from within the application. I haven’t used GitKraken in ages now since they’ve gone fully paid for commercial use, so I can’t say if such a thing still exists or not. But you can always use the [form on their website](https://www.gitkraken.com/contact) to send in feedback instead.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. In the latest version, it's not so hard to select the commit, click on the commit hash to copy it and run `git checkout pasted-hash`. This really shouldn't be difficult to add though, and would definitely be a nice feature to have built in.

Comment: I really don't understand how a application like this don't have a checkout feature... Even the "limited" version control of intellij have this.

Comment: Number one reason why I still prefer Git Extensions over Git Kraken (if you are on Windows).

Comment: So many better alternatives in Windows, but all my kingdom for a decent Git GUI in Linux.

Comment: End of 2018 and still not implemented... I sent them feedback and we'll see how they respond.

Comment: @DaniAvni Any word?

Comment: @BUInvent, On Nov they responded "We have an existing feature request for checking out commits in detached head state that's currently under review.  I gave that existing item a +1 to note your interest in that feature.". I guess we'll have to wait

Comment: Request this feature from within the tool. They have an open feature request for this, they told me today, and they'll up the priority.

Answer (score 9):

They finally implemented this feature [yesterday](https://support.gitkraken.com/release-notes/current/#version-621) (Sept. 25th, 2019).

> Users can now enter a detached HEAD state by clicking the commit you wish to checkout and selecting `Checkout this commit`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make a UNDO in the top bar. Anothe option can be reset to another commit using the right click on the commit.

Answer (score -8):

The way you do this is by right clicking on your desired commit and select "Reset  to this commit" and then choose "Hard - Discard all changes"

Comment: This is not a good idea, you are changing where the (master) branch points, potentially losing any changes made since the selected commit hash.

Much better to just drop back to the command line for the usually rare case where you want to checkout an unlabelled commit. Or as the accepted answer suggests create a (temporary) branch or tag at the commit first in order to checkout the commit.

Comment: No no no! Please don't try this unless you know what you're doing. This will not only do something entirely different that checking out a commit, but you'll lose any uncommitted changes and can break your branch