# How to git checkout such a particular commit using GitKraken?

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit, gitkraken

I am using GitKraken, a gui client of git vcs.
GitKraken is also a single place for all my Git repositories.
But i didn't find any option where i can go such a particular commit that i have already used in my git bash using 
"git checkout " command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to checkout old commit in git kraken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977015/how-to-checkout-old-commit-in-git-kraken)

Answer (score 6):

See "[Checkout a branch](https://support.gitkraken.com/working-with-repositories/branching-and-merging#checking-out-branches)":

You can right-click on any commit, select "create a branche here", and checkout that branch.

[image: Gitkraken creat branch here option for commit]

That way, you will avoid the detach HEAD branch, and will switch to the expected commit.